# Re enter without password after revoke salesforce oauth token

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce

I built a simple app that allows our customers to gather specific information from their Salesforce system. For authentication I used ["WebServer Flow"](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5), which allows a user to log in to our site with his Salesforce account.

I should of course allow the user to log out of his account. But for some reason, even though I send a Revoke request to Salesforce and get an OK response, when the user redirected again to the Salesforce login page, it automatically logs in to the previous account without re-entering details.

this is the logout action in my backend,

```
public async Task<ContentResult> LogOutFromSalseforce(string code)
{
    AuthenticationClient auth;
    bool hasAuth = AuthSessionWrapper.AuthDic.TryGetValue(code, out auth);
    if (!hasAuth) return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = "session expired" }), "application/json");
    var url = auth.InstanceUrl + _revokeEndpointUrl;
    var cl = new HttpClient();
    var res = await cl.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", auth.RefreshToken) }));
    AuthSessionWrapper.AuthDic.Remove(code);
    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { success = res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK }), "application/json");
}
```

And after call from client to this action he redirected to our login page.

I found that even if i call to this revoke endpoint from client it's not work.
only if the user enter in another tab to Salesforce and click logout there, he need to re enter his details to login again to our site.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If someone get into the same problem, I solved it with add "&prompt=login" to the login redirect url.